# Odoo 9c. List view couldn't be loaded

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I received error while try to open view in Odoo. Early evrything working fine. I added some data.

Today I try to do this again and recived error:

> Error
>
> List view couldn't be loaded

Model:

```
class partner_advert(models.Model):
    _name = 'pr_filials.partner_advert'

    name = fields.Char(string="Name")
    image = fields.Binary(string="Logo", required=True)
    adv_banner_data_ids = fields.One2many('pr_filials.adv_banner_data', 'partner_advert_id', 'Related advertising banners')
    landing_page_ids   = fields.One2many('pr_filials.landing_page', 'partner_advert_id', 'Related advertising pages')
```

views:

```
<menuitem id="partner_advert_menu" name="Advertising partners" parent="advert_pages_menu" action="partner_advert_list_action"/>
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="partner_advert_list_action">
    <field name="name">Advertising partners</field>
    <field name="res_model">pr_filials.partner_advert</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Add advertising partner
        </p>
    </field>
</record>
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="partner_advert_tree_view">
    <field name="name">partner_advert.tree</field>
    <field name="model">pr_filials.partner_advert</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Advertising partners list">
            <field name="id"/>
            <field name="name" string="Name"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="partner_advert_form_view">
    <field name="name">partner_advert.form</field>
    <field name="model">pr_filials.partner_advert</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Advertising partner">
            <sheet>
                <group>
                    <field name="name" string="Name"/>
                </group>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

Other fields have been removed. But even with single field 'name' the view does not work.

When I try to change pr_filials.partner_advert with another model everything works fine.

May you help me with this?

PS:

> pr_odoo_v9=# SELECT count(id) FROM public.pr_filials_partner_advert;
>
> ### count
>
> ```
>  3 (1 row)
> ```
>
> pr_odoo_v9=#

Comment: Is there more than that sentence as error message? If yes add it to your questions, please.

Comment: No. Only this error displayed (js-file). Odoo.log hasn't errors. In db all data present. I dublicated class and reentering data. All work fine.